# Bug in Subsonic 3.0.0.1? The ToString() override and DescriptorValue() cause errors

Tags: subsonic

In my web app, Subsonic 3.0.0.1 seems to be generating the code from the templates correctly *except* for two methods: ToString() and DescriptorValue().  And those methods are fine for all the tables but one -- a table named ContentType.  That shouldn't be a problem, correct?   The error I receive for each of the aforementioned methods is this:

'SubsonicTest.ContentType' does not contain a definition for 'ContentType' and no extension method 'ContentType' accepting a first argument of type 'SubsonicTest.ContentType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here are the generated methods that don't build:

```
public string DescriptorValue()
{
      return this.ContentType.ToString();
}


public override string ToString()
{
         return this.ContentType.ToString();
}
```

I do of course have a reference to the 3.0.0.1 assembly in my project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have two columns in your table, and the second column has the same name as your table. This isn't good naming :) and it's confusing the templates.